# Owner draw ComboxBox with CBS_DROPDOWNLIST style does not retain aero style

Tags: mfc

I am working on  MFC dialog based application in windows OS.

When doing ownerdrawing of items for CComboBox with CBS_DROPDOWNLIST style, I am losing rounded shape for the CComboBox, How to retain the aero style of it while doing owner-draw also?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know this won't be easy with owner draw. You may consider using `CMFCMenuButton` instead. This will create a drop-down button with a standard menu, you can endable/disable menu item etc.